# jdbcTemplate batchUpdate is throwing java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast

Tags: java, spring

I tried to add multiple datum to relatives table using `jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate`:

I tried to select the `maxid` from student table and have used in insert query as the id.

**This is my code:**

```
List<Relatives> relatives=student.getRelatives();
String sql3="Select Id,Name from Student where Id=(select Max(Id) from student)";
final Student student1= (Student) jdbcTemplate.query(sql3, new UserMapper5());  
String sql4 = " INSERT INTO Relatives (StudentId,RelativeId,YearId,ClassId,SectionId,RelationshipId,IsDeleted,CreatedBy,CreatedDate) "+
                 " Values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,GETDATE())";
int[][] updateCounts = jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql4, relatives, relatives.size(),
    new ParameterizedPreparedStatementSetter<Relatives>() {
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, Relatives relative) throws SQLException {
            ps.setInt(1, student1.getId());
            ps.setString(2, relative.getStudent().getName());
            ps.setInt(3, relative.getStudent().getYear().getId());
            ps.setInt(4, relative.getStudent().getClasss().getId());
            ps.setInt(5, relative.getStudent().getSection().getId());
            ps.setInt(6, relative.getRelationship().getId());
            ps.setInt(7, 0);
            ps.setInt(8,123);
        }
    }
);
```

I'm getting the below error When I tried to  insert multiple data to relatives table:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.cloudnexus.spring.model.Student

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will solve your problem:

```
final Student student1= (Student) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql3, new UserMapper5());
```

Also you can make your `UserMapper5` a generic one and avoid casting:

```
public class UserMapper5<T> implements RowMapper {

    public T mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        /// ...
    }
}
```

And then:

```
final Student student1= jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql3, new UserMapper5<Student>());
```

Comment: This worked for me, Thanks @Minar Mahmud for your help

Comment: Since i have used rowmapper that was  giving the result as List which was my problem, by using final Student student1= jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql3, new UserMapper5<Student>()); it was converted to object which solved my issue ...

Answer (score 2):

[jdbcTemplate.query](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreator-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-) with `RowMapper` returns a List, and then if not empty get the student:

```
List<Student> studentList = jdbcTemplate.query(...
if (!studentList.isEmpty()){ 
   Student student1 = studentList.get(0);
```

> Returns:
>   the result List, containing mapped objects

Comment: @PandianK how `UserMapper5` defined?

Answer (score 1):

Use `jdbcTemplate.queryForObject` instead which can return Object what you expect. Current method you are using returns List which is not you are expecting(as per the `sql query` it should return only one record).